# Asterisk not responding to app requests over sip

Tags: c#, asterisk, sip

I'm trying to make simple `click-to-call app`. I have asterisk server installed and i can make calls using free `softphone`. But when I send something using my app, i get no response.

I didn't work with sockets before. So, it could be the case.

Here's my code:

```
string registerHeader = "REGISTER sip:asteriskip;transport=UDP SIP/2.0\r\n";
string toHeader = "To: <sip:1@asteriskip;transport=UDP>\r\n";
string fromHeader = "From: <sip:1@asteriskip;transport=UDP>\r\n";
string callId = "Call-ID: 1\r\n";
string CSeq = "CSeq: 1 REGISTER\r\n";
string expires = "Expires: 3600\r\n";
string via = "Via: SIP/2.0/UDP myip:myport;branch=z9hG4bK-1\r\n";
string maxF = "Max-Forwards: 70\r\n";
string UA = "User-Agent: MySoftphone\r\n";
string contact = "Contact: <sip:1@myip:myport;transport=UDP>\r\n";
string contLength = "Content-Length: 0\r\n\r\n";

Socket cl = new Socket(SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
byte[] registerMsg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(registerHeader + toHeader + 
    fromHeader + callId + CSeq + expires+via+maxF+UA+contact+contLength);
IPEndPoint server = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("asteriskip"), 5060);
cl.Connect(server);
cl.Send(registerMsg);//(registerMsg, registerMsg.Length);
int bytesCount = 0;
do
{
    byte[] response = new byte[] { };
    cl.Receive(response);//(ref server);
    bytesCount = response.Length;
    string resp = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);
    Console.WriteLine(resp);
}
while (bytesCount == 0);
Console.ReadKey();
```

This request is nearly same as `softphone's`, took it from `wireshark`. But `softphone` gets response and this request doesn't. There should be Register CSeq 2, i tried to send it - still nothing, and if I'm not mistaken I should receive something like `401-Unauthorized` after 1st part of Register.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, i found that i was missing `tag` parameter. If `tag` is not set, server ignores requests.